# GEE Temporal Gap Filling - Fill Landsat 7 cloud masked pixels to produce one image

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat-7, composite, cloudmasking

Really new to GEE but trying to learn during my PhD...

I am trying to fill the gaps created from cloud masking the Landsat 7 imagery I have. I have filtered by the study area (geometry), the cloud mask and the time period (01/07/2000 to 31/10/2000).

I then return empty/white pixels when I map the image, which I expected but I need to fill these empty pixels with pixels that are not cloud covered in the next closest image in the time period.

What code can I apply to get one full image with all pixels being as temporally close as possible? This is to digitise a coastline. Below is the code I have so far, essentially I want the clipped composite to have no white gaps in at the end before exporting.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/ecbc21275df1e1093fbd582c6f5ca86e

https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Feleanorwratten1996%2FTutorialPractice1%3ACoastal%20Mapping%20Extraction%20Script

```js
// Apply cloud mask
function maskL457sr(image) {
  // Bit 0 - Fill
  // Bit 1 - Dilated Cloud
  // Bit 2 - Unused
  // Bit 3 - Cloud
  // Bit 4 - Cloud Shadow
var qaMask = image.select('QA_PIXEL').bitwiseAnd(parseInt('11111', 2)).eq(0);
var saturationMask = image.select('QA_RADSAT').eq(0);

// Apply the scaling factors to the appropriate bands.
var opticalBands = image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2);
var thermalBand = image.select('ST_B6').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0);

// Replace the original bands with the scaled ones and apply the masks.
return image.addBands(opticalBands, null, true)
      .addBands(thermalBand, null, true)
      .updateMask(qaMask)
      .updateMask(saturationMask);}

// Map the masking function over filtered date and bounds
var collection = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LE07/C02/T1_L2")
                     .filterDate('2000-07-01', '2000-10-31')
                     .map(maskL457sr)
                     .filterBounds(geometry);
Map.centerObject(geometry);
print(collection);


/////// THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO FILL IN ABSCENCE OF CLOUDY PIXELS USING TIME SERIES GAP FILLING

// Create mosaicked and composite image, then clip the composite image
var mosaic = collection.mosaic();
var composite = collection.median();
var clip_composite = composite.clip(geometry);

// Display the results.
Map.addLayer(collection, {bands: ['SR_B3', 'SR_B2', 'SR_B1'], min: 0, max: 0.3}, 'Filtered Collection');
Map.addLayer(mosaic, {bands: ['SR_B3', 'SR_B2', 'SR_B1'], min: 0, max: 0.3}, 'Mosiac');
Map.addLayer(composite, {bands: ['SR_B3', 'SR_B2', 'SR_B1']}, 'Composite 2000');
Map.addLayer(clip_composite, {bands: ['SR_B3', 'SR_B2', 'SR_B1'], min: 0, max: 0.3}, 'Clipped Composite 2000');
Map.addLayer(geometry);

//var clip_composite_fill = clip_composite.map(fillGap).select('SR_B3', 'SR_B2', 'SR_B1');

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: clip_composite,
  description: '2000',
  crs: 'EPSG:3413',
  region: geometry,
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 10000000000});
```